# WooCommerce rounding before calculate totals

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product

I'm using WooCommerce version 3.0+ as well as a price by user roles plugin which gives a % discount against prices.

We have an item in the shop which is £89.55. With a 30% discount applied this becomes £62.685. If you order 6 then the value is £376.11.

The final figure is correct.

However as I have WC settings set to 2dp, the item price shows as £62.69. Therefore invoices are incorrect showing as £62.69 x 6 = £376.11.

I've thought about using woocommerce_before_calculate_totals like from here:

[Dynamic cart item pricing not working on orders in WooCommerce 3.0+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43885585/dynamic-cart-item-pricing-not-working-on-orders-in-woocommerce-3-0)

My code is:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'adding_custom_price', 10, 1);
function adding_custom_price( $cart_obj ) {

if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
    return;

 foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
     $new_price = round($cart_item['data']->price,2,PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
     $cart_item['data']->set_price($new_price);
     #echo $new_price;
 }
```

}

The output from the echo $new_price is 62.69. But it seems set_price isn't working as the values in the cart are still showing as for 62.685.

So for example if I do 62.69 x 2 the subtotal is 125.37.

Any idea why set_price isn't working? I saw this:

[Woocommerce: $cart_item['data']->set_price is not working inside custom plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39867194/woocommerce-cart-itemdata-set-price-is-not-working-inside-custom-plugin)

But the answer on there doesn't work either.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to use **`WC_Product`** method [**`get_price()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_get_price) as `$cart_item['data']` is an instance of **`WC_Simple_Product`**.

Also you have to beware as the displayed prices in cart are already rounded by WooCommerce specific formatting functions.

So your functional code for WC 3.0+ will be:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'adding_custom_price', 10, 1);
function adding_custom_price( $cart ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        $product_price = $cart_item['data']->get_price(); // get the price
        $rounded_price = round( $product_price, 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP );
        $cart_item['data']->set_price(floatval($rounded_price));
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

---

You can check (test) by adding to the product price *(cart item)* a very little float number. You will see that the cart prices are really updated, replacing for example in the function:

```
$cart_item['data']->set_price( floatval( $rounded_price ) );
```

By

```
$cart_item['data']->set_price( floatval( $rounded_price + 0.2 ) );
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. It seems set_price is still not working even if I add a test value on. So it's not a rounding issue - the additional value such as 0.2 or even 100 is not showing in cart totals anywhere. get_price is working however because when I echo that it does show the correct rounded up value.

Comment: @rav I have tested this code on 2 different servers and it's working just fine. If you use `$cart_item['data']->set-price(25);` in your hooked function, you will see that all cart items are updated with a price of 25. So this methods as working perfect in `woocommerce_before_calculate_totals` hook.

Comment: Ok so tested as above using set_price - it works as you say. The problem on my side is due to using the Woocommerce Prices By User Role plugin. When I deactivated it the price was showing as 25. Switching it on overrides my code. Is there a way I can override this? Otherwise I'll do some research into looking for an alternative plugin.

Comment: I've added you but I can't message you until you accept my contact request